# SHA1 Message digest to plain-text

Tags: c, encryption, sha

How can I turn my message digest into plain-text (getting the original message back). I compute a message digest using the following function. The SHA1 code can be found in https://github.com/tylabs/quicksand_lite/blob/master/sha1.c I can not find a function that will make the conversion for me. Is there any algorithm that can do this?

I am also trying to decrypt and encrypt messages this is where the problem comes from.

```
int main()
{

  char qbits[5];
  char rbits[5];
  char ID[SIZE];   //User ID
  char message[SIZE];   //User message
  char shamessage[SIZE]; //The input message digest(sha1 result)

  char xor_result[SIZE]; //Sender XOR result---V
  char xor_result_receiver[SIZE];  //Receiver XOR result
  memset(xor_result, 0, sizeof(char)*SIZE);
  memset(xor_result_receiver, 0, sizeof(char)*SIZE);


  pairing_t pairing;   //The pair of bilinear map

  element_t P, Ppub, s, U, Qid, Sid;
  mpz_t messagehash;
  mpz_init(messagehash);

  printf("\n############SETUP############\n");
    printf("Please enter rbits:");
  scanf("%[0-9]", rbits);
    getchar();
  printf("\nPlease enter qbits:");
  scanf("%[0-9]", qbits);
    getchar();

  setup_sys(atoi(rbits), atoi(qbits), P, Ppub, pairing, s);
  printf("System parameters have been set!\n");
  element_printf("P = %B\n", P);
  element_printf("Ppub = %B\n", Ppub);


    printf("###########EXTRACT###########\n");
    element_init_G1(Qid, pairing);
  element_init_G1(Sid, pairing);
  printf("Plase enter your ID:");
  scanf("%[ a-zA-Z0-9+*-!.,&*@{}$#]", ID);
  printf("\nID=%s\n", ID);
    getchar();
    get_private_key(ID, pairing, s, Sid);
  get_public_key(ID, pairing, Qid);
  printf("##########ENCRPTION##########\n");
    printf("\nPlase enter the message to encrypt:");
  scanf("%[ a-zA-Z0-9+*-!.,&*@{}$#]", message);
  getchar();
  printf("The original message=%s", message);

    sha_fun(message, shamessage);   //Get the message digest
  printf("\nThe message hash=%s\n", shamessage);

    element_init_G1(U, pairing);
  encryption(shamessage, ID, P, Ppub, U, xor_result, pairing);
  printf("Send <U,V> to the receiver!\n");

  printf("##########DECRYPTION##########");
  decryption(Sid, pairing, U, xor_result, xor_result_receiver);
  printf("\nThe recovery message digest is %s\n", xor_result_receiver);
  printf("The original message digest is %s\n", shamessage);

  if (strcmp(xor_result_receiver, shamessage) == 0) {

    printf("Yeah!The message has been decrpted!\n");
  }

  else {
    printf("Oops!The message can not be decrpted!\n");
  }

  //Free space
  element_clear(P);
  element_clear(Ppub);
  element_clear(Qid);
  element_clear(Sid);
  element_clear(U);
  element_clear(s);
  pairing_clear(pairing);

  return 0;
}
```

And my output is a message digest but I need it to be plain-text.

```
############SETUP############
Please enter rbits:6

Please enter qbits:6
System parameters have been set!
P = [456, 103]
Ppub = [176, 88]
###########EXTRACT###########
Plase enter your ID:friedrich12

ID=friedrich12
Private key Sid = [184, 383]

Public key Qid = [99, 84]
##########ENCRPTION##########

Plase enter the message to encrypt:code
The original message=code
The message hash=E6FB06210FAFC02FD7479DDBED2D042CC3A5155E
U = [456, 103]
Public key Qid = [99, 84]

V=3D958162F64322BFC65D7655DFE6B61D89945F35
Send <U,V> to the receiver!
##########DECRYPTION##########
The recovery message digest is E6FB06210FAFC02FD7479DDBED2D042CC3A5155E
The original message digest is E6FB06210FAFC02FD7479DDBED2D042CC3A5155E
Yeah!The message has been decrpted!
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"turning your message digest into plain-text"_?

Comment: Getting the original message back.

Comment: Digest is kind of "summary". You can turn "summary" into a full text.

Comment: @DokuSoftware you can't. If the size of the message is say 1Mb, the size of the digest will still be only 64 bytes long. So getting the original 1Mb message back from the 64 bytes digest would be rather miraculous

Comment: In other words: 1) Cryptographic hashes such as SHA1 are *trapdoor functions*. 2) They contain *much* less information than the hashed data, so many different data can have the same hash. Conclusion - it is impossible to get the plaintext.

Comment: Unless the original message size <= message digest length, some information must have been lost.  In general, not possible.

Comment: Hint: read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), or rather [this](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/iguide-crypto-hashes.html)

Comment: @chux I am pretty sure the information is lost even for small messages, otherwise it would be "easy" to exclude the corresponding hashes from the potential collisions.

Comment: I made some edits to the post so you can see where the problem is from. I am trying to decrypt and encrypt messages using identity based encryption but I want to get back to a plain-text message not the message digest.

Comment: Did you even read the previous comments?

Comment: A message digest algorithm is *not* an encryption algorithm.  (It is not a compression algorithm, either).  It is not reversible.  Moreover, it's not just that no one has written the inverse algorithm yet -- it is specifically *designed* to be impossible to write that inverse algorithm.  That's the whole point.  (If you find a way to reverse it, you have "cracked" it; it was broken.)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Hashes are not trapdoor functions. A trapdoor function is one that is easy to compute in the forward direction but is hard to compute in the reverse direction unless you have special information, called the trapdoor. Hashes are many-to-one functions. Trapdoor functions are generally one-to-one functions (which is implied by the fact that they are invertible).

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right, have to brush up the terminology...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it is mathematically impossible to recover an original message from a message digest. A message digest is a **small** amount of information that is intended to act as a sort of fingerprint for a **large** amount of information. For example, in one of the simplest forms, a message digest might be simply the sum of the numerical values of the characters in a message. You obviously cannot recover the original message just from the sum of its characters. (Two messages that are anagrams would have the same sum, so the sum would not tell you which of the two messages was the original. And a message changed by increasing one character and decreasing another would have the same sum as the original message, so, again, the sum would not distinguish them.) This is just an example—actual cryptographic hashes are more complicated than simple sums.

Second, cryptographic hashes and the message digests they produce are usually **designed** to be difficult to invert. It is intended to be difficult to find **any** message whose digest equals a given value.

If you want cryptographic functions that change a message to a cryptic form and then invert it, you are looking for **encryption** and **decryption**, not hashes or digests.

Answer (score 0):

If you know every possible messages beforehand, you have the list of every of them, you can produces the SHA-1 digests for each, hoping there's no collision (btw, if you found one, please share). Then, at receive time, you lookup which SHA-1 you received and match with the known possible messages.

It's not secure, as an observer could identify the behavior of your system in the response of every SHA-1, or it could have access to the database of known message.

So it's almost pointless.

You could assign each message a arbitrary number, it would work the same, and it would be faster and shorter.